# Lipschitz constant and Jacobi method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, lipschitz-functions, jacobian

How to calculate the Lipschitz constant for the Jacobi iteration function?

For a question, I've rearranged it and change it into diagonally dominant system,

$$
\begin{matrix}
        3 & -1 & 1 \\
        1 & -8 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 & 5 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
x
$$
\begin{matrix}
        u\\
        v\\
        w\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

=$$
\begin{matrix}
        -2\\
        1\\
        3\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

How to find the Lipschitz constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on the homework right now! Just found the notes from lecture. There's a function phi(y) = Ty + v = (-D^-1 * N)y + D^-1 * b. The Lipschitz constant is ||T||, so essentially it's just the norm of -D^-1 * N from what my notes say. See you tomorrow in class J. Doe :p